# what is a mask image in image processing

Tags: opencv3.0

While working with OpenCV, I came across the function [colorChange](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/da0/group__photo__clone.html#ga6684f35dc669ff6196a7c340dc73b98e), in the photo module:

```
colorChange(InputArray src, InputArray mask, OutputArray dst, float red_mul=1.0f, float green_mul=1.0f, float blue_mul=1.0f)
```

Its second argument is a mask image. Would someone please tell me what is a mask image and what is it used for?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)

Comment: thanks Oliver! But could you please tell me what does the mask do with respect to this function itself.I mean, what is the criteria to choose a mask in case of the colorChange function?

Comment: In this particular case (and in most opencv functions) it should apply the color change only to the mask pixels, i.e., in the pixels with value 255 of the binary mask.

Comment: Thanks TFreitas ! This is what I was looking for!